# Refactoring same loop with different properties

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I've been refactoring some of my code, and I ran into a situation I wasn't sure on how to refactor, I can tell it should be done, just not sure how.

Here it is:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    double sum = 0;

    foreach(var cost in item.data)
    {
       sum += cost.value;
    }

    ListObject[count].Sum = sum;
    count++
}
```

Then I have the exact same loop below this one, with the only difference being the ListObject property. Like ListObject[count].Average = sum;

They are different datasources, so I can't put the Average in the sum.

How can I put this in a method that I could specify what property to use?

Comment: It seems item is never used for anything?

Comment: And where does `data` come from?

Comment: can you paste the complete code, with both loops? thanks

Comment: Is `count` reset after the code that you show but before the second loop that you mentioned?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia ah yep.

Comment: Assuming `data` is actually `item` I think your code is OK and can't be refactored further without losing readability.

Comment: Shouldn't `sum` be scoped inside the first loop, like `var sum = 0` so it doesn't mean anything outside the outer loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in an `Action` to execute to a method:

```
void ExecuteLoop(Action<int, int> callback, YourListType list)
{
    var count = 0;
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        sum = 0;

        foreach(var cost in data)
        {
           sum += cost.value;
        }

        callback(count, sum);
        count++
    }
}
```

and then when you call it:

```
ExecuteLoop((index, sum) => ListObject[index].Sum = sum, list);
```

or

```
ExecuteLoop((index, sum) => ListObject[index].Average = sum, list);
```

Comment: how would I pass my list source to loop through?

Comment: @timmy, see my edit please. I don't know what your list source is so I just put `YourListType`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Haven't learned this yet! Would you say this is best method for what i'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is supposed to set the `Average` properly. This way you calculate a **sum** in both calls but use it to set either `Sum` or `Average`.

Comment: @rook Yea, the math will be the in both calls. The only difference is the datasource, and the property to assign to.

Comment: @timmy: did you mean they are the same in both calls? Even though member names suggest something different, right? That being said, be aware that calling lambdas this way introduces some overhead - this is probably the only practical con. Unless you have extremely large data sources, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @rook Yea they are the same. Wouldn't bother with? What's would you call extremely large?

Comment: @timmy: Well, it depends. The point is only that the callback inside the loop involves additional method call with a context change. Unless you do some profiling it's impossible to say whether it matters at all. Good old rule: do not optimize prematurely. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about using LINQ?

```
list.Sum(i => i.value);
```

and

```
list.Average(i => i.value);
```

At the very least, this would clean up your inner loop. It's hard to tell on the outer loop because of the questions asked in the comments. Is item the same as data (for example)?